# java 8 datatime parse error

Tags: java-8, localdate

I am trying to convert a string to `LocalDate` object. but I get the following error.

```
private LocalDate getLocalDate(String year) {
        String yearFormatted = "2015-01-11";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd");
        LocalDate dateTime = LocalDate.parse(yearFormatted, formatter);
        return  dateTime;
    }
```

here is the error

```
Caused by: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2015-01-11' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfMonth=11, WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2015, MonthOfYear=1},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1855) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
    at java.time.LocalDate.parse(LocalDate.java:400) ~[na:1.8.0_102]
```

Comment: Try `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");`

Comment: can you explain why?

Comment: Because `LocalDate` doesn't know how to deal with week-based-year (the 'Y' in the formatter). It needs a year ('u') or year-of-era ('y') instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) says, the capital `Y` in a format pattern is for week-based-year, that is, the year that the week number belongs to. This is not always the same as the calendar year (though most often it is). Java is smart enough to recognize that it cannot be sure to get a date out of week-based year, month and day-of-month, so it throws the exception instead.

Since the format of your string agrees with the default `LocalDate` format (ISO 8601), the simplest solution is to drop the formatter completely and just do:

```
    LocalDate dateTime = LocalDate.parse(yearFormatted);
```

With this change, you method returns a date of `2015-01-11` as I think you had expected. Another fix is to replace `YYYY` with either lowercase `yyyy` for year-of-era or `uuuu` for a signed year (where 0 is 1 BC, -1 is 2BC, etc.).